# SQL Server while using bcp log file is not coming in English

Tags: sql-server, bcp

While using `bcp` to bulk upload data from a file, the log/out file (`-o` switch) is not being used in English. The server's language is English, and user used to execute `bcp` also has language as English.

`bcp` is executed from command line. Any way to get the log file in English?

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. `-o` is the output file; the data inserted is the output of the query. BCP doesn't change the "language" of the data, it has no translate feature. It's not going to see the word "Hello" and write "Bonjour"; if it wrote "Bonjour" that's what's in the data returned from SQL Server.

Comment: Yes the output file, contains the error message, if the copy failed and how many rows copied, how much time it took to copy the data etc if the copy is successful....these messages are not coming in English.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the client utilities install (MsSqlCmdLnUtils.exe) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) if are downloading in a machine with language setting other than English, the installer will come in that language! So I have download the above install in a Machine with English and reinstalled, now the bcp logs are coming in English.